# PowerShell Start-Job Running

Tags: powershell, jobs, start-job

I need help with jobs in PowerShell. I wrote the script below and the job runs but it actually doesn't do anything. I've tried a few things like `Invoke-Command`, but PowerShell waits for completion before moving to the next line which is not what I'm looking for. I need to run this code in parallel with some remaining code underneath it.

```
#Arhive Files in Data Folder
$ArchiveDataFiles = {
    function test {
        $ArchiveDataFilesList = Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\Data\*.pdf" | Select- 
        Object -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object -Descending
        for ($c = 0 ; $c -lt $ArchiveDataFilesList.count; $c++) {
            $ArchiveDataFile = $ArchiveDataFilesList.Item($c)

            if ((New-TimeSpan -Start ([DATETIME] ($ArchiveDataFile.ToString().SubString(8,15) -replace "_", " ").Insert(13, ":")) -End ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime())).TotalHours -gt $ArchiveDataHours) {
                $ArchiveDataFileDepartureDateTime = ($ArchiveDataFile.ToString().SubString(8,15) -replace "_", " ").Insert(13, ":")
                $ArchiveDataFileAirlineCodeFlightNumber = $ArchiveDataFile.ToString().SubString(0,7)
                $ArchiveDataFileDepartureIATA = $ArchiveDataFile.ToString().SubString(24,3)
                $ArchiveDataFileArrivalIATA = $ArchiveDataFile.ToString().SubString(28,3)

                "---Archiving Release---
Flight Date/Time: $ArchiveDataFileDepartureDateTime
Flight: $ArchiveDataFileAirlineCodeFlightNumber
Departure: $ArchiveDataFileDepartureIATA
Arrival: $ArchiveDataFileArrivalIATA
File Name: $ArchiveDataFile
"

                $DateTimeNow = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "z"
                if (!(Test-Path "$PSScriptRoot\Log")) {
                    New-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Log" -Type "directory"
                }
                if (!(Test-Path "$PSScriptRoot\Log\DataLog.txt")) {
                    New-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Log" -Name "DataLog.txt" -Type "file"
                }
                Add-Content "$PSScriptRoot\Log\DataLog.txt" -value "---Archive Release--- 
$DateTimeNow
Flight Date/Time: $ArchiveDataFileDepartureDateTime
Flight: $ArchiveDataFileAirlineCodeFlightNumber
Departure: $ArchiveDataFileDepartureIATA
Arrival: $ArchiveDataFileArrivalIATA
File Name: $ArchiveDataFile
"

                if (!(Test-Path "$PSScriptRoot\Data")) {
                    New-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Data" -Type "directory"
                }
                if (!(Test-Path "$PSScriptRoot\Archive")) {
                    New-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Archive" -Type "directory"
                }
                Move-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Data\$ArchiveDataFile" -Destination "$PSScriptRoot\Archive"
            }
        }
    }
}

Start-Job -InitializationScript $ArchiveDataFiles -ScriptBlock {
    Start-ArchiveDataFiles
} -Name ArchiveDataFiles
```

Comment: One possible problem: If `Start-ArchiveDataFiles` is a _function_ in the caller's scope, the job won't see it.

Comment: Turns out you have to use relative path (C:\) and not $PSScriptRoot.

I also had to call the function at the bottom.
}
}
}
Start-ArchiveDataFiles
}